# I have two buttons and I need to change color of either of the two in Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am having two buttons in my HTML file

```
<div>
  <button  ion-button outline (click)="selectUnit(200)">200gms</button>
  <button  ion-button outline (click)="selectUnit(400)">400gms</button>
</div>
```

So when the user clicks on 200gms, I want to highlight its color and if he clicks 400, I want it to highlight the 400.

I researched a lot online and found solutions like -

```
<button [attr.newColor]="addAttribute ? '' : null">Test</button>
```

But what happens here is, the attribute will change to true, and highlight both the buttons.

I just want to highlight the button which was pressed and stay highlighted till another button is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a property from that component to keep the selected value, and then use the `color` attribute from the `button` to change it based on the current selected value.

Please take a look at this **[Working stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-p45job)**.

[image]

**Component**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  public selected: number;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  public selectUnit(unit: number): void {
    this.selected = unit;
  }

}
```

**View**:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h2>Welcome to Ionic!</h2>

  <p>Selected: {{ selected }}</p> 

  <div>
    <button [color]="selected === 200 ? 'secondary' : 'primary'" ion-button outline (click)="selectUnit(200)">200gms</button>
    <button [color]="selected === 400 ? 'secondary' : 'primary'" ion-button outline (click)="selectUnit(400)">400gms</button>
  </div>
</ion-content
```

Please notice that I use `[color]="selected === 200 ? 'secondary' : 'primary'"` to select the right color for each button based on the value of the `selected` property.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you for such a detailed answer.

Comment: Glad to help @neerajSaxena :)